# How to cut porcelain

Tags: bathroom

I need to shorten this porcelain leg to fit under a porcelain sink (the reason is complicated and not relevant).  I’m concerned that any cutting/sawing/grinding may crack the porcelain.  Any ideas are welcome.

[image]

Comment: How much to you need to remove?

Comment: About 4" from top

Comment: I suggest that whatever method you use, first try cutting a smaller amount (say 1") first to gain experience and verify the method is suitable. Then go for the final cut.

Comment: Suggest you have a 'plan B', such as a painted wooden replacement. This is a tough project to do perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your local home center should have a carbide grit blade that attaches to a hacksaw handle. It looks like a thick piece of wire coated in coarse sand or a wide blade coated in a coarse material They are typically used to cut ceramic tile. Start slowly while going through the glazing. A piece of tape wrapped around the piece should limit chipping at the cut edge.

Answer (score 0):

I have had very good results using a diamond blade to cut granite; much better than masonry blades. Using it a regular 7" circular saw. Two cautions : there must be a steady supply of water to essentially flood the cut and I bought the M K brand blade 20 years ago ( As I remember it cost about $ 20. ). I recently made a 20" long cut in one inch thick granite with it. That being said , are you sure it is porcelain ? A great many tubs and counter tops ( in the US) are made of polyester with filler and called many things like "marble". They are easier to cut than porcelain.